# Problem understanding a step in derivation of Lorentz Transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I need to understand a step in the derivation of Lorentz Transformation.

[image: taken from thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com]

[image: taken from thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com]

I cannot understand how can we equate the equations 1 and 2. I am talking about the relation between ct, x, y, z. Where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Euclidean space $R^3$ you know that
$$
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
$$
Add to this the fact that
$$
r = c \cdot t
$$
$$  
\text{(space = velocity} \cdot \text{time)}
$$
and you can easily obtain the relation between $x$, $y$, $z$ and $c \cdot t$:
$$
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (c \cdot t)^2
$$
(do the same thing for the primed system)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how r2=x2+y2+z2

Comment: @rahulgarg12342 [Read this!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Euclidean_distance_in_various_coordinate_systems)

Comment: Thank you @ShyGuy. Just one more thing, in my question what exactly are x, y and z. Are they any points or is the distance between them and the origin the radius?

Comment: And can you also please explain to me how the equation would be applied n this case. Please, as this is important to me and I do not know from where the equation came and neither its derivation. To be frank, the hyperlink does not explain that.

Comment: But we have x, y and z. Not only x and y.

Comment: In Euclidean $n$-space, the Euclidean distance $d$ between two points, $A = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $B = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)$, is defined, by generalization of the Pythagorean theorem, as:
$$
d = \sqrt{(a_1 - b_1)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2 + ... + (a_n - b_n)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)^2}
$$
----
In your exercise: $n = 3$, the distance is labelled "$r$", $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (x, y, z)$ , $B = (b_1, b_2, b_3) = (0, 0, 0)$.

Comment: @aShyGuy +1 if you can integrate these comments you have made into the answer itself.:-)