# A confusion in the Derivation of Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity

[image: http://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/]

My doubt is in the equation (1) and (2). Aren't x,y and z also the radiuses?

**EDIT**
Thank you guys for trying to give a wonderful explanation but I figured out the answer myself and it was just my silly interpretation. I thought the the value of ct on x axis would be equal to ct and forgot that the value is given by a perpendicular and not an arc (of the sphere). I was thinking that where the sphere touches x axis, that is the value of ct but it isn't. The value of ct for x is given by a point on the axis that lies perpendicular to the axis.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93469/problem-understanding-a-step-in-derivation-of-lorentz-transformation

Comment: @KyleKanos it wasn't answered properly then. I want a separate explanation.

Comment: I'm going to strongly disagree with the whole "it wasn't answered properly" part of your comment. aShyGuy's answer is correct; the problem, it seems, is that you *didn't understand* his answer. And are now asking more-or-less the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the coordinates as a single object: $\mathbf{x}=\left(x,\,y,\,z\right)$. 
A point $P$ located at $\mathbf{P}=\left(a,\,b,\,c\right)$ would look like this:

[image]

Now what is the distance from the origin ($\mathbf{x}=(0,\,0,\,0)$) and $\mathbf{P}$? For this we need to use the Pythagorean theorem: *the square of the diagonal is equal to the sum of the squares of the sides* (e.g., $d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$). In 2 dimensions, this is done by

[image]

$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=r^2$$
But if we wanted to find the distance from some point that *isn't* the origin, we use
$$r^2=\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(y-y_0\right)^2$$
where $x,\,y$ are the positions of the point and $x_0,\,y_0$ the reference position. In the subsequent discussion, $x_0=y_0=0$.

In 3D, we can actually do the above 2D slice twice. Solve for $r$ in the $x$-$y$ plane and then solve for $d$ in the $r$-$z$ plane (using $x=a$, $y=b$, and $z=c$):
$$
r^2=a^2+b^2\to r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$
$$
d^2=r^2+c^2\to d^2=\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+c^2=a^2+b^2+c^2
$$
We could also have done this in the $y$-$z$ plane first:
$$
r^2=b^2+c^2\to r=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}
\\
d^2=r^2+a^2\to d^2=\left(\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\right)^2+a^2=a^2+b^2+c^2
$$
so clearly the ordering of it doesn't matter, we get $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ as the distance from the origin to the point $P$ when doing it both ways.

Next, what happens if we let $y=b\to y=-b$? Since we take the square of $y$, we get $y^2=\left(-b\right)^2=+b^2$ which doesn't change anything, our distance is still $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. The same thing happens if we swap the other values for their negatives. That means that there are *at least* 8 points $P$ that have *identical* distances from the origin.

Let's try using some values, just to get an idea here. Suppose we let $\mathbf{P}=\left(1,2,2\right)$. The distance $d$ is then
$$d=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}=\sqrt{1+4+4}=\sqrt{9}=3$$
If we consider a sphere with constant radius (i.e., $d$ does not change), then if we change $x=1\to x=0$ we must have that 
$$\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=3$$
 Obviously $y=z=3=d$ is *not* a solution because 
$$\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=\sqrt{9+9}=\sqrt{18}>4>d$$
Equally as well, $x=y=z=3=d$ is not a valid solution because
$$\sqrt{3^2+3^2+3^2}=\sqrt{9+9+9}=\sqrt{27}>5>d$$
So **clearly** $x,\,y,\,z$ are **not also the radius**. *Individually*, the values could be the radius, but that would require the other two values being zero:

$$\sqrt{3^2+0^2+0^2}=\sqrt{9+0+0}=\sqrt{9}=3=d$$

Comment: I understood it completely now. I still have a strong point and will be posting it tomorrow because I will have to draw it in a notebook and take a picture. Thanks for your effort though. You might find me stubborn but I am thinking of it in another way.

Answer (score 1):

The *radius* is the distance from the origin to any point on the sphere at time *ct*. If you measure this distance along the $x$ axis then the radius vector is $(ct, 0, 0)$. Likewise, measured along the $y$ axis the radius vector would be $(0, ct, 0)$ and along the $z$ axis it would be $(0, 0, ct)$. However if you measure to some point that doesn't lie on any of the three axes the radius vector would be $(x, y, z)$ where the three numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ are related by:

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (ct)^2 $$

Comment: but the point where the sphere touches the three axes is also the radius. Isn't it?

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: yes, there are an infinite number of possible radius vectors. The three radius vectors that lie along the axes are special cases of the many possible radius vectors.

Comment: But then that would make the equation wrong if x, y and z are also the axes because they are three and squared while ct is only once squared.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: the expression is just the 3D version of Pythagoras' theorem. It states that the distance $r$ between the points $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(x, y, z)$ is given by $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. Remember that for some point not on any of the axes the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ must all be less than $ct$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying John but it seems contradictory to me. Aren't the values on the axes also equal to the value of the radius because the sphere is touching the axes at length ct.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: yes at the points where the sphere intersects the axes, and **only** at those points, the value on the axis is equal to the radius $ct$. At all other points on the sphere the individual values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ at that point are all less than $ct$. I'm not sure I see where the contradition is.

Comment: See I will tell you the contradiction. ct is the radius. But if we see, then we find that even the individual values of x, y and z also the radius. So it should be ct = x (or y or z).

Comment: $(ct, 0, 0)$ i.e. the point where the sphere intersects the $x$ axis is a radius vector, and at this point $x = ct$. However $(ct/\sqrt{3}, ct/\sqrt{3}, ct/\sqrt{3})$ is also a radius vector and at this point $x = ct/\sqrt{3}$. So $x$ does not have to be equal to $ct$ at a radius.

Comment: Sorry John but I didn't quite get you!